# File Explorer Search - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-search

I'm trying to find folders that contain the string `GEN       (`.

That's the 3 letters G, E, and N, followed by 7 spaces, then a left parenthesis.

I've tried

```
"GEN       ("
*GEN       (*
kind:=folder "GEN       ("
kind:=folder *GEN       (*
kind:=folder *"GEN       ("*
```

and a number of more basic, generic syntaxes and what is consistently returned are folders with the word "general" in them (or nothing at all in some cases).

It's as if multiple spaces are just crunched to a single space.

I'm searching a network share if that matters...

I have never understood Microsoft's implementation of search. Back in XP and 7 I could search the exact name of a file that I'm staring at and Explorer would be like, "nope, don't see it."

Comment: What folder are you in when you start your search? Windows will only search inside the folder that was open (and in subfolders if the option is enabled). If you want to search the whole PC, open "This PC" then start your search from there, and make sure the "All subfolders" option is active. See [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2xoD.png).

Comment: Yeah, I was in a folder level above where I wanted to search and I had "subfolders" enabled. No big deal, thank you for your time!

Comment: Well, that's very weird that it's not working for you, 'cause I experimentally created a `GEN       (MOO)` (with 7 spaces) folder, and searched for "GEN (" (with one, and with 7 spaces), and it worked fine for me both times.

Comment: Hmm. First, I appreciate the effort! Now I realize that I was not quite descript in my post. I'm starting with a mapped drive to a server (server is running WinServer 2012R2). So, like I click the L drive in the left pane of Explorer (Navigation pane) and the 1st level folders show in the right pane. Within these folders are definitely folders with the string I indicated - GEN [seven spaces] then an open parens.

With no quotes, obviously it catches things like general.doc but with quotes, it gives me results with "gen" followed by a single space but not the folder with 7 spaces.